# Як називати мешканців Старих Петликовець?

Tags: розмовна-українська

Як назвати мешканців села Старі Петликівці та схожих сіл із назвою, що складається більше ніж з одного слова?
В Інтернеті мені не вдалося знайди відповідей, лише, що мешканців Кривого Рогу так і називають "мешканці Кривого Рогу", а Івано-Франківська - "іванофранківчани". Отож, з жителями Старих Петликівців така ж ситуація, чи їх можна назвати інакше?

Comment: можна утворити за прикладом *іванофранківчан*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [мовній консультації](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine35-23.pdf) з приводу утворення назви мешканців маємо таку думку:

> На характер творення назв жителів впливають і інші фактори. Серед них
>   — особливості сполучуваності основи і словотворчого суфікса. Їх
>   поєднання відбувається за певними правилами, закономірностями, що
>   діють в українській мові. **Так, зокрема, не може поєднуватися однаковий
>   кінцевий звук твірної основи і початковий звук словотворчого суфікса,
>   не сполучаються звуки, що чергуються між собою, не поєднуються
>   ідентичні суфікси, за допомогою яких творяться найменування жителів і
>   самі географічні назви**, тому, наприклад, від найменувань населених
>   пунктів на -ов, (-ів, -ев) назви жителів не утворюються за допомогою
>   складного суфікса -івц-і, бо він містить однаковий з суфіксом основи
>   елемент
>   -ів.

У книзі І. Фаріон «Мовна норма» маємо таке спостереження:

> Другою за продуктивністю є словотвірна модель із суфіксами **-анин,
>   -янин, -чанин.** Їхня синонімна повноправність із -ець не викликає сумнівів, однак **їм властиве поєднання з твірними основами на:
>   -иц-я**: Вижниця — вижнич-ан-ин — вижнич-ан-к-а — вижнич-ан-и; Вінниця — віннич-ан-ин — віннич-ан-к-а — віннич-ан-и;
>   -ець: Кременець — кременч-ан-ин — кременч-ан-к-а — кременч-ан-и; Кролевець — кролевч-ан-ин — кролевч-ан-к-а — кролевч-ан-и;
>   **-ц-і**: Чернівці — чернівч-ан-ин — чернівч-ан-к-а — чернівч-ан-и; Ярмолинці — ярмолинч-ан-ин — ярмолинч-ан-к-а — ярмолинч-ан-и;
>   -цьк: Донецьк — донеч-чан-ин — донеч-чан-к-а — донеч-чан-и; Луцьк — луч-ан-ин — луч-ан-к-а — луч-ан-и;
>   -ак: Судак — судач-ан-ин — судач-ан-к-а — судач-ан-и; Токмак — токмач-ан-ин — токмач-ан-к-а — токмач-ан-и;
>   -ч: Галич — галич-ан-ин — галич-ан-ка — галич-ан-и; Дрогобич — дрогобич-чан-ин — дрогобич-чан-к-а — дрогобич-чан-и; (-к)и: Прилуки —
>   прилуч-ан-ин — прилуч-ан-к-а — прилуч-ан-и; Суми — сум '-ян-ин,
>   сум-ець — сум '-ян-к-а — сум '-ян-и, сум-ц-і.

Отже, найбільш природнім виглядатиме назва старопетліківчанин, старопетликівчанка, старопетликівчани. Однак у тій же [публікації](https://uk-ua.facebook.com/chystamova/posts/385246674964782) зазначається, що суфікси **-анин, -янин, -чанин** не повинні превалювати над питомим українським -ець:

> Суфікси -анин, -янин, -чанин треба залишити хіба у тих позиціях, де не можна вжити суфікса -ець: Вінниця - вінничанин - вінничанка - вінничани.